# Unable to pick image from Gallery from Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I am developing an app which needs picking up content from `Internal/External Storage` like photos, media etc ..... but in `Android Oreo`, it is not working ...

Comment: What's the error? Are you asking for runtime permissions? We need to see some code & the error mate.

Comment: As this is not a free programming service, please show us what you have tried so far, and please study [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have granted run-time permission for storage.

This can be done either by setting it explicitly in the settings of your android device or asking for the permission during run time.

You can check this link [how run time permission works](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Also please check whether you have used content provider for the same or not

You can check this link [working with content providers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html)

Sample Library (you can use any other available on GITHUB) : [Karumi/Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter)

Comment: if you have any example or link of repository that shows that how it works?